# Assembly (68k) stack operations

Tags: assembly, stack

I am having trouble making this code work and was hoping to get some insight here.

The program is supposed to read two numbers from input (>0 and <300) and output their sum and product. We are supposed to use the stack to pass values to subroutines.

My program runs and reads the input and displays output, but it is not the correct output. I'm assuming my stack operations are off, but I can't figure out what's missing.

Here is my code so far.

EDIT: I have a functioning code except for the multiplying part. I know for certain that the next items on the stack are the input numbers but the Multiplier subroutine does not calculate the correct product value. Can anyone take a look at the subroutine and check what is wrong?
            ORG    $1000
    START:                  ; first instruction of program

```
* Put program code here

First:
    move    #14,D0      Display string
    lea     prompt1,A1  
    trap    #15      
    move    #4,D0       Input num1 to D1
    trap    #15
    move.l  D1,-(SP)    push num1 to stack
    move.l  D1,D4       move num1 to keep

    move.l  #300,D2     Upper limit  
    cmp     D1, D2      Compare user input to upper lim
    bhi     Second
    blo     Error1

Second:    
    move    #14,D0      Display string
    lea     prompt2,A1 
    trap    #15    
    move    #4,D0       Input num2
    trap    #15
    move.l  D1,-(SP)    push num2
    move.l  #0,-(SP)    make room for sum on the stack
    move.l  D1,D5       move num2 to keep

    move.l  #300,D2     Upper limit  
    cmp     D1, D2      Compare user input to upper lim
    bhi     MoveOn
    blo     Error2

MoveOn:
    *add
    bsr     Adder
    move.l  (SP)+,D1    pull sum, D1 = sum
    lea     (8,SP),SP   clean up stack
    move    #14,D0      Display string
    lea     result1,A1
    trap    #15
    move    #3,D0
    trap    #15

    bsr     newLine

    move.l  D4,-(SP)    push num1 to stack
    move.l  D5,-(SP)    push num2 to stack

    *multiply
    bsr     Multiplier
    move.l  (SP)+,D1    pull product, D1 = prod
    lea     (8,SP),SP   clean up stack
    move    #14,D0      Display string
    lea     result2,A1
    trap    #15
    move    #3,D0
    trap    #15

    SIMHALT             ; halt simulator

Error1:
    move    #14,D0 
    lea     error,A1
    trap    #15
    move    (SP)+,D3    Pull incorrect num1 from stack
    bsr     newLine
    bra     First

Error2:
    move    #14,D0  
    lea     error,A1
    trap    #15
    move    (SP)+,D3    Pull incorrect num2 from stack
    bsr     newLine
    bra     Second



*----------------------------
        offset  4+4
sum     ds.l    1
num2   ds.l    1
num1    ds.l    1
        org     *

Adder
    link    A0,#0           create stack frame
    move.l  (num1,A0),D0  
    add.l   (num2,A0),D0   
    move.l  D0,(sum,A0)    
    move.l  (SP)+,D0        
    unlk    A0
    rts

*----------------------------
    offset  4+4
prod    ds.l    1
num4    ds.l    1
num3    ds.l    1
        org     *

Multiplier
    link    A0,#0           create stack frame
    move.l  (num3,A0),D0    
    mulu    (num4,A0),D0    
    move.l  D0,(prod,A0)    
    move.l  (SP)+,D0        
    unlk    A0
    rts

newLine 
    movem.l d0/a1,-(SP)         push d0 & a1
    move    #14,d0              task number into D0
    lea     crlf,a1             address of string
    trap    #15                 display return, linefeed
    movem.l (SP)+,d0/a1         restore d0 & a1
    rts                         return

* Put variables and constants here
prompt1 dc.b    'Sláðu inn fyrri tölu: ',0
prompt2 dc.b    'Sláðu inn seinni tölu: ',0
error   dc.b    '** Tala er ekki á réttu bili, reyndu aftur **',0
result1 dc.b    'Summa talnanna er: ',0
result2 dc.b    'Margfeldi talnanna er: ',0
crlf    dc.b    $d,$a,0
    END    START        ; last line of source
```

Comment: Did you run it through the debugger?

Comment: Just a semantic comment: *Push incorrect num2 from stack*. Things are "popped" off of a stack, not "pushed" off of a stack. :)

Comment: I'm using easy68k, where is the debugger?

Comment: When you execute `bsr Adder` or `bsr Multiplier` is the code in those subroutines taking into account that the `bsr` pushes the program counter on the stack when attempting to access the operands from the stack? So the operands will be at offsets +4 and +8 off on the stack inside of those routines.

Comment: I have forgotten much about 68k assembly, but when you are addressing parameters with (num1,A0), what do you expect value of num1, num2 (and so on) offsets to be and why?

Comment: I have updated the code in OP and added a message.

Answer (score 1):

A trap is a bit like a sub-routine pointer on which you will jump. In case of a sub-routine (where you jump using JSR or BSR), the 68k need to "remember where you came from". For that, he saves the 4 bytes of the adress (in fact te PC) of where was called the sub-routine.
The difference is that a trap function run in superviseur mode. So inside a trap function you can write where you want, do what you want as you are in superviseur mode.
As the superviseur mode is saved in the status-register, this mean that, before entering the trap function, the 68k has to save both PC to return AND status-register. PC is 4 bytes, SR is 2 so the 68k use 6 bytes on the SP to protect the data.
So first, you must do:
move.w d0,-(sp)
move.l d1,-(sp)
trap #15
addq.l #6,sp
Don't forget to add to SP after the trap call, in order to correct the fact that, before the trap you've change the stack.
Inside the trap function, you must consider the fact that the 68 has also put something in the SP.
So you must add 6 bytes (2 bytes for the SR and 4 for the PC) to the offset you use over the SP, in order to get back the values you put on it.
In this exemple, you can read values in the trap function using:
move.l 6(sp) -> d1
move.w 8(sp) -> d0

But also, it depend on what you save in your SP inside the trap function.

Sorry, my Atari machine is far from me, so no test; So I don't remeber if the 68k stack first SR then PC or PC then stack... :(

Hope this wil help
Regards
Peter